# Featured Content Slider - Change on hover - slides flickering

Tags: jquery

can anyone help?

I've added a [featured content slider](http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/featured-content-slider-using-jquery-ui/) to a website I'm developing for a client, and and one of the comments they've asked is whether the slide transition can occur on hover, and then when clicking on the slide (or indeed the ui-tabs) taken to the destination URL.

The jQuery I've got is the standard that comes along with the demo (I'm still learning you see)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#featured").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);  
    $("#featured").hover(  
    function() {  
        $("#featured").tabs("rotate",0,true);  
    },  
    function() {  
    $("#featured").tabs("rotate",5000,true);  
    }  
    );
    });
```

It has the added 'pause on hover' function.

Anyhow, the HTML for the tabs is as below:

```
  <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
    <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item ui-tabs-selected" id="nav-fragment-1"><a href="#fragment-1"><span class="panelTitle">Find a<br />
      <span class="panelTitleMain">Boat</span></span> <span class="panelCopy">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></a></li>
    <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-fragment-2"><a href="#fragment-2"><span class="panelTitle">Find an ABYA<br />
      <span class="panelTitleMain">Broker</span></span> <span class="panelCopy">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></a></li>
    <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-fragment-3"><a href="#fragment-3"><span class="panelTitle">TBC<br />
      <span class="panelTitleMain">TBC</span></span> <span class="panelCopy">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></a>&lt;</li>
  </ul>
```

I've managed to get the slider to change on mouseover with the following, but now the images are flickering when loading.

```
$("#featured").tabs({event: 'mouseover', fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);  
$("#featured").hover(  
function() {  
    $("#featured").tabs("rotate",0,true);  
},  
function() {  
$("#featured").tabs("rotate",5000,true);  
}  
);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Yes I too ended with flickering when loading.

But I now found solution for it.Just remove the  code `'fx:{opacity: "toggle"}'` from function, it will work fine.

I think the toggle and mouseover both are not needed.